# Setting react-router link prop with a condition statement returns a syntax error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am trying to write a render function that sets onlyActiveOnIndex={true} on a react-route  component when passed the correct argument.

So instead of repeating the whole link I tried writing this code:

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div className={`navbar navbar-${this.props.linksData.length}`}>
        {this.props.linksData.map((linkData) => {
          return(
            <div className="navbar-link-container" key={linkData.to}>
              <Link
              activeClassName="navbar-active-link"
              {linkData.to === '/' ? onlyActiveOnIndex={true} : null}
              to={linkData.to}>
                <i className="navbar-icon material-icons">{linkData.icon}</i>
                <span className="navbar-link-text">{linkData.text}</span>
              </Link>
            </div>
          )
        })}
      </div>
    )
  }
```

But I get the following syntax error:

> Syntax error: Unexpected token, expected ... (16:15)

What would be the correct way to conditionaly set a prop on a react component (If the link does not point to the index route I do not want the property to be there at all).

For now I wrote the following workaround:

```
onlyActiveOnIndex={linkData.to === '/' ? true : false}
```

But what if in the future I want to set conditional props?

Comment: I guess you could write a conditional component instead of conditional props. Something like `{linkData.to === '/' ? <Link ... props when true ...></Link> : <Link ... props when false ...></Link>}`. It brings more verbose but it is the only way I know to achieve what you need.

Comment: Another way is using `...` spread operator <Link ...{onlyActiveOnIndex: linkData.to === '/' ? true : null}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
<Link
  activeClassName="navbar-active-link"
  onlyActiveOnIndex={linkData.to === '/'}
  to={linkData.to}>
    <i className="navbar-icon material-icons">{linkData.icon}</i>
    <span className="navbar-link-text">{linkData.text}</span>
</Link>
```

As for your optional props question, something like this should work,

```
render() {
  let props = {}
  showName && (props.name = 'Tyler')
  showAge && (props.age = 27)

  return <MyComponent {...props} />
}
```

Where you're only settings properties on the object if a certain condition is met, then, you can spread that object into your component.

Comment: It works and it is more elegant than my previous workaround. In this use case it is everything I need - but the question still remains, can I set a optional property, in case I only need to pass a prop if it is defined in the controller component (so if the prop is null not setting the prop at all)

Comment: @MihaŠušteršič Edited my answer to answer your question.